# To compare two DRIVER_OBJECT for equality?

Tags: c++, c, windows, kernel, driver

I get two instances of DRIVER_OBJECT. I use ObReferenceObjectByName() on a driver name obtained from registry to get one DRIVER_OBJECT. The second I get from a DEVICE_OBJECT structure. I want to check if the two DRIVER_OBJECTs are equal, in order to understand whether the driver i read from registry is the same as that loaded for that device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## WARNING

this answer may not be the most accurate, I am just going by old memory of hooks written in wee hours many years ago:

If anyone knows better and I have made a mistake kindly drop me a note below and I'll fix.

## Disclaimer

ObReferenceObjectByName is undocumented and risky, you shouldn't be using it (e.g. it will fail under Windows 7) without understanding the limitations.

## Answer

DRIVER OBJECT is:

```
typedef struct 
{
     SHORT Type;
     SHORT Size;
     PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject;
     ULONG Flags;
     PVOID DriverStart;
     ULONG DriverSize;
     PVOID DriverSection;
     PDRIVER_EXTENSION DriverExtension;
     UNICODE_STRING DriverName;
     PUNICODE_STRING HardwareDatabase;
     PFAST_IO_DISPATCH FastIoDispatch;
     LONG * DriverInit;
     PVOID DriverStartIo;
     PVOID DriverUnload;
     LONG * MajorFunction[28];
} DRIVER_OBJECT;
```

Compare the DriverStart (length is specified by DriverSize) to see if they map to the same memory addresses and see if you get anywhere.

However if you are trying to remain compatible I think you are probably better off to see if DriverInit, DriverStartIo and DriverUnload in each of your objects point to the same addresses.  DriverSection / DriverSize / DriverStart are all undocumented and should be avoided.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I came across a very easy and elegant solution which I would like to share. The pointer to the DRIVER_OBJECT (i.e, the address of the DRIVER_OBJECT) is a hexadecimal number. And since there is only one DRIVER_OBJECT for one driver, comparing this address (hexadecimal number) for equality does the work with charm.

```
PDRIVER_OBJECT a;
PDRIVER_OBJECT b;
/* get the values of a and b
...
...
*/
if (a == b)
{
// they point to the same DRIVER_OBJECT.
}
```